# Prevent user from clicking the same button?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm really new to java and I'm learning javafx while doing this project.The code sends rows and cols to another class when a button is clicked. My logic send the row and col accordingly to another class. But i want to prevent the user from clicking the same button. How would i go about doing that. I know there's a `setDisable` function but how would go implementing it.

```
for (row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
        button[row][column] = new Button();
        //  button[row][column].setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
        button[row][column].setPrefSize(50, 50);
        button[row][column].setOnAction(new clickEvents(row, column));
        //no setters, directly passed rows and cols to clickEvents Class
        tileGrid.add(button[row][column], row, column); //adds buttons to the tile grid
        //node , row position in grid, column position in grid
    }
}
```

Revised

```
for (row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
        button[row][column] = new Button();
        //  button[row][column].setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
        button[row][column].setPrefSize(50, 50);
        button[row][column].setOnAction(new clickEvents(row, column));
        temprow = row;
        tempcol = column;
        //if (row == temprow && column == tempcol)
        if (button[row][column].isPressed()) {
            button[row][column].setDisable(true);
        }

        //no setters, directly passed rows and cols to clickEvents Class
        tileGrid.add(button[row][column], row, column); //adds buttons to the tile grid
        //node , row position in grid, column position in grid
    }
}
```

Comment: disable the button

Comment: [mcve] please .. also I would suggest reading and understanding a basic tutorial on how to use buttons (hint: it doesn't use isPressed :), the javafx wiki page has references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisable(boolean)).

```
button.setDisable(true);
```

Works on any component that inherits from Node, by the way, so you can disable pretty much anything in your scene.

When you create the button, set a boolean called `clicked`, initialized to false. When the user clicks the button, the handler fires, and sets the boolean to true. Then you have a bit of logic that branches on `clicked`. If true, do nothing (since the button was already previously disabled), if false, disable the button.

Comment: @DIt0Mad If the answer helped, click the checkmark to the left of the question to let others know what helped you.I tried to leave the implementation as an exercise for you, but if you need help implementing the actual code, let me know.

Comment: so can i use the isPressed method instead of setting a boolean?  like

Comment: i posted up top

Comment: I figured it out i basically got the event source and if its clicked once, the button was disabled.

Comment: @DIt0Mad That works too. isPressed is an event with a very short lifecycle, but you only really need things to happen once, so it's OK.

Comment: most probably, isPressed is the wrong thingy: from your - a bit scarce :) - description I assume that you want the action to happen exactly once, right? Disabling on pressed might lead to not happening at all, f.i. when the user pressed the mouse and then escape.

Comment: @kleopatra it is for a battleship game. I wanted to disable the button so the user is prevented from clicking the same button again. (placing ship in the same coordinate)

Comment: @DIt0Mad In that case, using the boolean is probably better, because it's something you can control from anywhere in your program, not just that event handler. Untying it from the event gives you a lot of control and reliability.